# Laravel use old DB connection

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm developing a project in laravel and I have to change the db connection.
I add a new connection and set this like default but when I run the app it uses the old connection and I don't understand why.

I'm not using `.env` just setting `config/database.php`.

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'DB2'),

'connections' => [

    'DB2' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'IP'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DB2'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '*****'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'DB1' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '2222'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DB1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '****'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
    ],



],
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just clear the config cache using the following commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```